# mysql get X(point) along with join

Tags: mysql, join, point

I am trying to run a select query joining multiple tables. Ont of the tables has got a column coordinate with point type. Everything works correctly but in joins it does not allow me to select X(coordinate) or X(point(coordinate)).

I can select coordinate in the join and can select X(coordinate) directly on the table but both together dont work.

```
select x(coordinate) from location_coordinate
```

The above one works

```
select ca.campus_id,
ca.campus_name,
ca.status_code,
ca_loc.location_id,
ca_loc.address,
ca_coo.coordinate,
ca_loc.locality_id,
ca_loc.area_id,
ca_loc.city_id,
ca_loc.state_id,
loc_locality.name as locality_name,
loc_area.name as area_name,
loc_city.name as city_name,
loc_state.name as state_name
    from campus_account ca 
     left join location ca_loc 
        on ca_loc.location_id=ca.location_id 
    left join location_coordinate ca_coo
        on ca_loc.location_id=ca_coo.location_id
    left join location_master loc_locality
        on(ca_loc.locality_id = loc_locality.location_master_id)
    left join location_master loc_area
        on(ca_loc.area_id = loc_area.location_master_id)
    left join location_master loc_city
        on(ca_loc.city_id = loc_city.location_master_id)
    left join location_master loc_state
        on(ca_loc.state_id = loc_state.location_master_id);
```

This also works. But if i try to do

```
select ca.campus_id,
ca.campus_name,
ca.status_code,
ca_loc.location_id,
ca_loc.address,
ca_coo.X(coordinate),
ca_loc.locality_id,
ca_loc.area_id,
ca_loc.city_id,
ca_loc.state_id,
loc_locality.name as locality_name,
loc_area.name as area_name,
loc_city.name as city_name,
loc_state.name as state_name
from campus_account ca 
     left join location ca_loc 
        on ca_loc.location_id=ca.location_id 
    left join location_coordinate ca_coo
        on ca_loc.location_id=ca_coo.location_id
    left join location_master loc_locality
        on(ca_loc.locality_id = loc_locality.location_master_id)
    left join location_master loc_area
        on(ca_loc.area_id = loc_area.location_master_id)
    left join location_master loc_city
        on(ca_loc.city_id = loc_city.location_master_id)
    left join location_master loc_state
        on(ca_loc.state_id = loc_state.location_master_id);
```

It does not select and gives me an error saying X is not a column.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `X(ca_coo.coordinate)` not `ca_coo.X(coordinate)`.

Comment: Actually just came online to post the same answer. I figured it out.. I am a silly person..Marking your answer. Thanks